# How to count non-null/non-blank values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have data like the following:

[image: Data]

And what I want is to count the PONo, PartNo, and TrinityID fields with a value in them, and output data like this:

[image: Desired Output]

How can I do this counting in SQL?

Comment: @Adrian -Only idea I had was to use isnull() to somehow test the field, but the value could be an empty string also.  Plus I can easily add the 0 if its null, but how to add 1 if its not null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
 Job_number, Item_code,
 case when RTRIM(PONo) = '' or PONo is null then 0 else 1 end +
 case when RTRIM(PartNo) = '' or PartNo is null then 0 else 1 end +
 case when RTRIM(TrinityID) = '' or TrinityID is null then 0 else 1 end 
 as [Count]
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Job_Number = t.Job_Number ,
       Item_Code  = t.Item_Code  ,
       "Count"    = sum( case ltrim(rtrim(coalesce( PONo      , '' ))) when '' then 0 else 1 end
                       + case ltrim(rtrim(coalesce( PartNo    , '' ))) when '' then 0 else 1 end
                       + case ltrim(rtrim(coalesce( TrinityID , '' ))) when '' then 0 else 1 end
                       )
from dbo.my_table t
group by t.Job_Number , t.Item_Code
```

If you want to exclude data where all the tested fields are null or empty, add a `having` clause:

```
having sum( case ltrim(rtrim(coalesce( PONo      , '' ))) when '' then 0 else 1 end
          + case ltrim(rtrim(coalesce( PartNo    , '' ))) when '' then 0 else 1 end
          + case ltrim(rtrim(coalesce( TrinityID , '' ))) when '' then 0 else 1 end
          ) > 0
```

Easy!

Comment: Similiar idea to Adrian above, but I think his might perform better because there are less function calls (no coalesce)?

Comment: I doubt you'd see any noticable difference in performance. I just tend to avoid `OR`. It makes my type more than I would otherwise. Further, with `coalesce`, I only type the column name once. To be more efficient, the `ltrim`/`rtrim` calls are likely extraneous as well, unless you have to worry about whitespace other than a space character: SQL compares strings by conceptually padding the shorter to the length of the longer with spaces. A string consisting of, say, a CR+LF pair, wouldn't then compare equal to '' as it be compared to a string consisting of 2 spaces.